# How can i fetch specific values from this array like ProductName and price?, i have tried map method but it only works with one value

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
const products = [{
    productId: 1,
    productName: 'Tablet',
    price: 120,
    Image: 'source',
    isPublished: true,
    isAvailbe: false,
  },
  {
    productId: 2,
    productName: 'Microphone',
    price: 100,
    Image: 'source',
    isPublished: true,
    isAvailbe: true,
  },
  {
    productId: 3,
    productName: 'Smart TV',
    price: 120,
    Image: 'source',
    isPublished: false,
    isAvailbe: true,
  },
  {
    productId: 4,
    productName: 'Itel',
    price: 70,
    Image: 'source',
    isPublished: true,
    isAvailbe: false,
  }
];

const result = products.map((item) => item.productName)
console.log(result);
```

Comment: What are you expecting as output/result? (give an example)

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely use map with multiple values, that is its purpose. Just wrap the returned values in brackets to create object. For convenience you can also use destructuring to extract values from input object and shorthand syntax to assign them to the returned object:

```js
const products = [ { productId: 1, productName: 'Tablet', price: 120, Image: 'source', isPublished: true, isAvailbe: false, }, { productId: 2, productName: 'Microphone', price: 100, Image: 'source', isPublished: true, isAvailbe: true, }, { productId: 3, productName: 'Smart TV', price: 120, Image: 'source', isPublished: false, isAvailbe: true, }, { productId: 4, productName: 'Itel', price: 70, Image: 'source', isPublished: true, isAvailbe: false, },

];

const result = products.map(({ productName, price }) => ({ productName, price }));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this easy method

const result = products.map(({ productName, price }) => ({ productName, price }));
console.log(result);

Answer (score 0):

You could write a little function that accepts the array, and a query array of the properties you want returned. It [`maps`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over each object, and then uses [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to create a new object with only those properties that matches the ones specified in the query.

(Note: I've lowercased the `image` property in the data, and fixed the spelling of `isAvailable`.)

```js
const products = [ { productId: 1, productName: 'Tablet', price: 120, image: 'source', isPublished: true, isAvailable: false, }, { productId: 2, productName: 'Microphone', price: 100, image: 'source', isPublished: true, isAvailable: true, }, { productId: 3, productName: 'Smart TV', price: 120, image: 'source', isPublished: false, isAvailable: true, }, { productId: 4, productName: 'Itel', price: 70, image: 'source', isPublished: true, isAvailable: false}];

function findProps(arr, query) {
  return arr.map(obj => {
    return Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, key) => {
      if (query.includes(key)) acc[key] = obj[key];
      return acc;
    }, {});
  });
}

const query1 = [ 'productName' ];
const query2 = [ 'productName', 'isAvailable', 'price' ];

const data1 = findProps(products, query1);
const data2 = findProps(products, query2);

console.log(data1);
console.log(data2);
```

Additional documentation

- [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/keys)
- [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)